# Can I execute an external process via MySQL on table change?

Tags: mysql, trigger, linux

When using triggers, if an update is done to a table then a trigger is executed. This is very convenient. But, what I would need is to execute an external script.
Is it possible to configure MySQL so that on a trigger/change of a value in a table an external process/script is executed?

Comment: So for every row update, an external application would be called? And if 4000 rows are updated, the application would be launched 4000 times? You think that would be wise? And if you had a million rows updated?

Comment: Even if the update frequency is low, there are several other serious issues with such an approach. See: [Catch-22 of the Active Database](http://karwin.blogspot.co.uk/2006/10/catch-22-of-active-database.html)

Comment: @ypercube:Interesting link.It is based on "triggers fire at the time of the operation, not the time of the commit". I was not aware of that.In this case it seems that triggers are useless in any case

Comment: As simple example, I found this blog with an simple example: [Call an external program form MySQL Trigger](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) I found this example easy to understand. :) Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, and it also makes for a security threat.

Anyway, to make that happen you would need to create (program, compile and install plugin) you own UDF - [User Defined Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html). It's a C/C++ code, so you can do anything you like in there.

Comment: Hi Shlomi, could I persuade you to elaborate on how UDF can make a security threat?

Comment: @Morten I'll give you the extreme. Suppose the `UDF` call is this: `SELECT EXECUTE_ON_BOX('rm -rf /important/data')` and the `UDF` just accepts given string and executes it.